# Create multi-view control in windows form

Tags: c#, multiview

When using ASP.NET I was often using MultiViews,Is there a control that can be used in a C# Windows Forms Applications like `MultiView`, I try `Tab control` can help to do that but if any other control to make multi-view without using Tab control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no controls "from box", that you need. I can recommendate to you use WPF technology, if it's possible by your business requirement. WPF contains feature like Data templates selector,  which can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem and just implemented my own, using Panels